# ASP.Net Wizard Control on a Mobile browser

Tags: asp.net, android, vb.net, controls, wizard

We are using a .net wizard control for a mobile website.  Everything works great except on android devices when the user exits the browser to take a call or send a text message. When the user returns to out web page the android browser is refreshing the web page.  Our problem is when the web page refresh the wizard is losing the view state So if they are in the middle of the wizard there previous work is lost. I wanted to see if any one had any ideas on how to combat this.  Is there a way to persist the wizard even if the user refreshes the webpage?

I basically want to make my asp.net wizard control truly stateless.

Comment: I found out that the issue was related to Ajax and it was causing the state of the wizard to be lost on the refresh.

Comment: Removing Ajax has fixed the issue.  I now use the asp.net ajax update panel with in each wizard step that needs ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing some data in the session variable that keeps track of the wizard progress should solve this.  If you want to make it work for longer periods of time you will need to implement a solution that uses the user profile.

Comment: The problem is that the wizard control loses its view state info.

Comment: disable view state on the control?